# Share on LinkedIn available comment length on new UI

Tags: linkedin-api

The [LinkedIn API documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) specifies that requests to Share on LinkedIn have a maximum user comment length of 700 characters.

For users on the old LinkedIn user interface, posts made through the Share on LinkedIn API display the full comment length.  Users on the new LinkedIn UI, however, have the comments on their shares made through the API truncated at 256 characters.  Users on the new UI have the full 700 character length when posting directly on linkedin.com.

Is this a bug in the API?  Is the documentation out-of-date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In more recent testing I found that the posts showed the full 700 character length in the new UI.  It looks like this is no longer an issue.